# Avoid calling same javascript plugin multiple time for the same selector

Tags: javascript, plugins, javascript-objects

Here's my plugin code:

```
( function() {
    this.Modal = function( selector, options ) {
        // Define option defaults 
        var defaults = {
            open: false
        }

        this.options = extendDefaults( defaults, options );

        alert();
    }

    function extendDefaults( source, properties ) {
        var property;
        for ( property in properties ) {
            if ( properties.hasOwnProperty( property ) ) {
                source[ property ] = properties[ property ];
            }
        }
        return source;
    }
}() );
```

Simply I need a way to prevent call the plugin again for the SAME selector if it has already called.

To be more clear if i try to initialize the plugin by doing this:

```
var firstSeelctor = new Modal( '.button' );
var secondSeelctor = new Modal( '.button' );
```

I need to call the first one and ignore the second one because it's already called for the same selector at the first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store selectors somewhere (*directly in the function constructor for example*) that you have already created and then check it during every instance creation.

```js
(function() {
  this.Modal = function modal(selector, options) {
    if (!modal.instances) {
      modal.instances = {};
    }

    if (modal.instances[selector]) {
      return modal.instances[selector];
    }

    modal.instances[selector] = this;

    var defaults = {
      open: false
    };

    this.options = extendDefaults(defaults, options);
    console.log('created for selector: ' + selector);
    // alert();
  }

  function extendDefaults(source, properties) {
    var property;
    for (property in properties) {
      if (properties.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
        source[property] = properties[property];
      }
    }
    return source;
  }

  var firstSeelctor = new Modal('.button');
  var secondSeelctor = new Modal('.button');
  var thirdSeelctor = new Modal('.button-2');
  
  console.log(firstSeelctor === secondSeelctor); // true, because it's the same instances
}());
```

Comment: Thank you very much, But please I need something if you make this for me I will be thankful for you, You make in your code that if the plugin called with the same selector return can rather than this called the defined object? To understand me more make secondSeelctor variable return the object of firstSeelctor (The defined one for the same selector), Please do that for me.

Comment: Ok, I've done it. This is a singleton instance for every uniq selector

Comment: Really thank you but there's a small bug please check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62229248/if-passed-element-is-already-initialized-return-its-instance-javascript-plugin -- thank you for your efforts really don't know what to say for you.

Comment: You are welcome! If you don't have any questions on the current point please mark my answer as *answer* and lets move on to the next question :)

Comment: Done and really you are a good person. I am waiting for you in the next question.