# Check if passed element is already initialized return its instance javascript plugin

Tags: javascript, object, plugins, javascript-objects

Plugin code:

```
( function() {
    this.Modal = function modal( selector, options ) {
        // If there's a passed element is already initialized return its instance
        if ( !modal.instances ) {
            modal.instances = {};
        }
        if ( modal.instances[ selector ] ) {
            return modal.instances[ selector ];
        }
        modal.instances[ selector ] = this;

        // Plugin options
        var defaults = {
            open: false
        };
        this.options = extendDefaults( defaults, options );
        selector.style.setProperty( 'background-color', 'red' );
    }

    function extendDefaults( source, properties ) {
        var property;
        for ( property in properties ) {
            if ( properties.hasOwnProperty( property ) ) {
                source[ property ] = properties[ property ];
            }
        }
        return source;
    }
}() );
```

To run the plugin:

```
$( window ).on( 'load', function() {
    $( '.button' ).each( function() {
        var myPlugin = new Modal( this );
    } );
} );
```

HTML Code:

```
<button class="button">First Button</button>
<button class="button">Second Button</button>
<button class="button">Third Button</button>
```

The wrong on the code that the first button only will read the plugin and gets the red background and the second and third buttons will return the instance of the first button, And I don't why this happens the buttons has the same class, yes but there are different elements.

I need every button called from the plugin gets the red background color and at the same time avoid initialized multiple times (If the passed element is already initialized return its instance).

Comment: "avoid initialized multiple times (If the passed element is already initialized return its instance)" Please, explain what do you mean by *element is already initialized*? Maybe you have an example of this case

Comment: @v.kostenko I mean if the element has initialized by the plugin, To understand me more if the element gets the background red. If the element gets the red background ( initialized by the plugin) why initialized it's again? Just return its instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. The problem is in objects approach here because the keys of the object can be only strings. And when we are trying to so smth like this `modal.instances[ selector ] = this;` we actually will have this `modal.instances['[object HTMLButtonElement]'] = this;` for any of the html button element. So the solution is to use [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) approach, because the keys of the map can be an objects.

```js
(function() {
  const modalInstances = new Map();

  this.Modal = function(element, options) {
    if (modalInstances.has(element)) {
      console.log('return instance for: ' + element.innerHTML);
      return modalInstances.get(element);
    }

    modalInstances.set(element, this);

    // Plugin options
    var defaults = {
      open: false
    };
    this.options = extendDefaults(defaults, options);
    element.style.setProperty('background-color', 'red');
  }

  function extendDefaults(source, properties) {
    var property;
    for (property in properties) {
      if (properties.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
        source[property] = properties[property];
      }
    }
    return source;
  }
}());

$(window).on('load', function() {
  $('.button').each(function() {
    var myPlugin = new Modal(this);
  });
  
  // we will use already careated instances here, see the console.log
  $('.button').each(function() {
    var myPlugin = new Modal(this);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="button">First Button</button>
<button class="button">Second Button</button>
<button class="button">Third Button</button>
```

Comment: The last question please, In my plugin I have a method to destroy the plugin should I add something in this method to destroy its Instances? If yes what it will be? Something like const modalInstances = null;

Comment: Or modalInstances.delete( selector ); ?

Comment: It depends how you would like to destroy the `Modal`. If you need to destroy it for whole set of elements use [modalInstances.clear()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/clear). If you need to destroy it only for one element you can just delete it from the `modalInstances` via [modalInstances.delete(element)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/delete)